# Windows Server 2008 Cdonts issue

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Cdonts is not working in server 2008 (im using 32bit)

i tried copying cdonts.dll to windows/system32 folder
did regsvr32 
it failed

any alternatives?

-Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDONTS is deprecated (around the time of XP, I believe?)
Here are 2 common replacements.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp

http://www.aspcode.net/ASPMail-SMTPsvgMailer-.aspx

Comment: What he said. CDONTS will not work on Win2K8. Use CDOSYS instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you have the 64-bit version. You have to put cdonts.dll in the windows\SysWOW64 folder and then run
regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cdonts.dll

You will also have to edit the application pool of your site and set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to True.

Answer (score 2):

Someone seems to have successfully installed CDONTS on Windows 2008 x64 on [IISLogs.com](http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/getting-cdonts-to-work-on-windows-server-2008-x64). I did not try myself though.

Here his procedure :

1. Copy CDONTS.dll from another server to C:\Windows\SysWOW64
2. Run regsvr32 c:\windows\SysWOW64\cdonts.dll
3. Grant the appropriate permissions on C:\inetpub\mailroot\pickup (I granted USERS group Modify permissions).  You could get permission denied if the folder security isn't adjusted.
4. I'm assuming you have installed the SMTP Service located in Server Manager > Features > SMTP Server option
5. Make sure when you when you install the SMTP service, you enable Relay for localhost > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services (IIS6) > SMTP Virtual Server > Right click, Properties > Access Tab > Relay button > Add 127.0.0.1 in the option.   Also enable logging for additional troubleshooting.

Comment: Spot on `Grant the appropriate permissions on C:\inetpub\mailroot\pickup (I granted USERS group Modify permissions). You could get permission denied if the folder security isn't adjusted.`

Comment: I copied over CDONTS.dll from my old Win 2003 (32-bit) Server to a Win 2012r2 64 bit machine (Virtual machine) It worked with out a hitch.